# Any tricks to get rid of boilerplate when constructing proofs of absurd predicate on enums?

Tags: haskell, boilerplate, dependent-type, idris, proof-of-correctness

Let's say I have

```hs
data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Grape | Orange | Lemon | {- many others -}
```

and a predicate on that type,

```hs
data WineStock : Fruit -> Type where
    CanonicalWine : WineStock Grape
    CiderIsWineToo : WineStock Apple
```

which doesn't hold for `Banana`, `Orange`, `Lemon` and others.

It [can be said](http://www.thenewsh.com/~newsham/formal/curryhoward/) that this defines `WineStock` as a predicate on `Fruit`; `WineStock Grape` is *true* (since we can construct a value/proof of that type: `CanonicalWine`) as well as `WineStock Apple`, but `WineStock Banana` is *false*, since that type is not inhabited by any values/proofs.

---

Then, how can I go about using effectively `Not (WineStock Banana)`, `Not (WineStock Lemon)`, etc? It seems that for each `Fruit` constructor besides `Grape` and `Apple`, I can't help but have to code up a case split over `WineStock`, somewhere, full of `impossible`s:

```hs
instance Uninhabited (WineStock Banana) where
    uninhabited CanonicalWine impossible
    uninhabited CiderIsWineToo impossible

instance Uninhabited (WineStock Lemon) where
    uninhabited CanonicalWine impossible
    uninhabited CiderIsWineToo impossible

instance Uninhabited (WineStock Orange) where
    uninhabited CanonicalWine impossible
    uninhabited CiderIsWineToo impossible
```

Note that:

- the code is repetitive,
- LoC will explode when the predicate definition grows, gaining more constructors. Just imagine the `Not (Sweet Lemon)` proof, assuming there're many sweet alternatives in the `Fruit` definition.

So, this way doesn't quite seem satisfying, almost *impractical*.

Are there more elegant approaches?

Comment: Many of the old Haskell idioms don't change in dependently-typed systems. "Make illegal states unrepresentable" holds at the type-level too: I don't think you should even be able to construct those impossible types. I'd probably structure this example as (something roughly like) a type of fruits that can make wine `data WineFruit = Grape | Apple` and other fruits `data Fruit = WineFruit WineFruit | Banana | Orange | Lemon`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, that approach starts to fall apart when you want to add `PieFruit`, `SaladFruit`, `WeaponFruit`, etc.

Comment: Given that you're in idris, why are you defining a datatype for `WineStock`? Can't you just define `isWineStock` as a value level function and use it in proofs where appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@slcv is right: using a function that computes whether a fruit satisfies a property or not rather than building various inductive predicates will allow you to get rid of this overhead.

Here is the minimal setup:

```
data Is : (p : a -> Bool) -> a -> Type where
  Indeed : p x = True -> Is p x

isnt : {auto eqF : p a = False} -> Is p a -> b
isnt {eqF} (Indeed eqT) = case trans (sym eqF) eqT of
                            Refl impossible
```

`Is p x` ensures that the property `p` holds of the element `x` (I used an inductive type rather than a type alias so that Idris doesn't unfold it in the context of a hole; it's easier to read this way).

`isnt prf` dismisses the phoney proof `prf` whenever the typechecker is able to generate a proof that `p a = False` automatically (via `Refl` or an assumption in the context).

Once you have these, you can start defining your properties by only enumerating the positive cases and adding a catchall

```
wineFruit : Fruit -> Bool
wineFruit Grape = True
wineFruit Apple = True
wineFruit _     = False

weaponFruit : Fruit -> Bool
weaponFruit Apple  = True
weaponFruit Orange = True
weaponFruit Lemon  = True
weaponFruit _      = False
```

You can define your original predicates as type aliases calling `Is` with the appropriate decision function:

```
WineStock : Fruit -> Type
WineStock = Is wineFruit
```

And, sure enough, `isnt` allows you to dismiss the impossible cases:

```
dismiss : WineStock Orange -> Void
dismiss = isnt
```